# QT and Crypto++ with /MTd

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, crypto++

I have two QT 5.5 projects with MSVC2013 32bit compiler. The first is Qt console application and is using crypto++ and this two in the pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd
```

The second is Qt widgets application where is dialog based GUI builded. Individually, each starts successfully, but also individually the GUI project with the same additions in the pro file like these above is givving the same old error:

> qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for
>   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value
>   'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj

Is there way to unite those two projects somehow? Also please explain the meaning and the difference between:

```
multi-threaded DLL(/MD)
multi-threaded (/MT)
```

What is the link between dynamic libraries and /MD, and between static and /MT?

Comment: [Difference between MD MT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)

Comment: You already asked this question and got a link to an existing Q+A that explains what you have to do.  There is very little reason to expect another outcome, you *must* explain why you don't know how to rebuild Qt.

Comment: Why to rebuild QT? I found a way for debug mode for crypto++, but it is not working for release mode! See my answer below.

Comment: Closely related (your other question): [Rebuild Crypto++ 5.6.2 for /MD release under Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33263734). It talks about fixing the broken VCUpgrade process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary':
> value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
> ```

This is due to mixing and matching C/C++ runtime libraries.

Crypto++ has four projects: ***`Cryptlib`***, ***`Cryptest`***, ***`Cryptdll`*** and ***`Dlltest`***. To further complicate matters, ***`Cryptlib`***, ***`Cryptest`*** have DLL-Import configurations re-used by ***`Cryptdll`*** and ***`Dlltest`***. Once you understand what's going on it makes a lot of logical sense.

You are linking against non-DLL-Import ***`Cryptlib`***, and it uses static linking. You need to switch to linking against a dynamically linked runtime library. For that, see [Compiling and Integrating Crypto++ into the Microsoft Visual C++ Environment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof). Its old, but it still applies.

You should also ***avoid*** anything with `DLL_Output` in its path. Though it uses proper runtime library linking, you are attempting to link against a DLL. The DLL exists for one purpose - as a security boundary for a FIPS 140-2 validated module. Its usually ***not*** what you are looking for, and usually the ***wrong*** library for the job.

Because you should also ***avoid*** anything with `DLL_Output`, open Configuration Manager and delete anything DLL related (for exampe, ***`DLL-Import Release`***). You should also completely delete the ***`Cryptdll`*** and ***`Dlltest`*** projects to simplify your life.

Comment: The solution is to REBUILD  cryptop 5.6.3rc5 insted of BUILDING the library(criptlib project 32bit relsease or debug in batch build) with Code Generation configurations to /MD or /MDd for each project. If it does not work see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263734/rebuild-crypto-5-6-2-for-md-release-under-visual-studio-2013?noredirect=1#comment54427733_33263734) link.